# Standing roadside: shouldn't it be "on the roadside" or "at the roadside"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality-in-context

I was reading this page and came accross this sentence:

> But there is one other attraction of the race that gets those standing roadside to scream almost as loudly: The publicity caravan -- La Caravane Du Tour.

I would have written it as "standing on the roadside".

What would have been the difference?

I am also wondering what type of structure is that? As far as I know, roadside is neither adjective nor adverb. Does it have anything to do with "to stand"? Is "stand" a linking verb here? Is it a kind of ellipsis?

---

Reference: https://edition-m.cnn.com/2017/07/17/sport/tour-de-france-caravan/index.html?r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Comment: _Roadside_ can be used adjectivally and adverbially. See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roadside), scroll down to the middle, oh and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roadside). Your example is just one of many instances where it as an adverb modifies an action.

Comment: @EddieKal I usually consult Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries and non of those dictionaries lists the word as adjective or adverb. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Cardinal  No need to be elitist.  Merriam-Webster is a partnership of two very long-established dictionaries, and definitely a reliable source.  "Roadside" is most certainly used like an adjective, e.g. **a roadside attraction**, although Cambridge and Oxford might just consider that a compound noun.

Comment: @EddieKal No, it cannot be used as an adverb. In fact, the Merriam-Webster link you provide only shows it as an adjective. To *stand roadside* is ungrammatical. (Although it's understandable if you silently add in the missing syntax that's suggested in the question.)

Comment: @Cardinal [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roadside) doesn't actually label it as an adjective, but it does say "*[often as modifier]*," which means it's used attributively and *acts* as an adjective. It's effectively the same thing. However, you ***are*** right that it's not used adverbially. The sentence as written in your question is not syntactically correct.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes it factually can, and "to stand roadside" is most definitely grammatical. _Sergeant Wyatt Foster of the North Country Sheriff's Criminal Investigations Division came to be standing roadside shortly after 7 A.M...; one can make out a man standing roadside holding a lantern...; That's why we see reporters standing roadside when reporting on traffic matters_  and [so many more](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22standing+roadside%22)

Comment: @JasonBassford Some sources actually list a category of words as _noun-adverbs_, referring to nouns that appear where adverbs would normally go and doing adverbial jobs. There has been several eons-old discussions on this topic on ELU already.

Comment: @EddieKal You could argue that anything could be used as an adverb. But doing so would be to produce something so awkward as to be strange or even incomprehensible. The use of *stand roadside* here is awkward and strange. It should not be used in the way that it has been. People use language in strange ways all the time. It doesn't mean that good writers will. I could point to examples of any number of terrible things, claiming that they were *grammatical* because they were used. Nonetheless, the majority of people would not do so.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't know how prescriptivism has seeped into this discussion. I am not sure if grammar purism is ever a healthy approach. I don't know about "anything could be used as an adverb", but don't you see the same logic can be applied to your point as well? You stated [_to stand roadside_ is] "understandable if you silently add in the missing syntax", but if you just started adding things, you could argue any word was of any function/part of speech.

Comment: @EddieKal You're simply saying *anything goes* and pointing to examples where some people have said something. You could make the same argument for *any* question that asks if something is acceptable or not. And in the final sentence in your last comment, you made *exactly* that point. I'm saying that if you take the sentence *as it is*, without adding something to make it meaningful, then it's ungrammatical. Nobody asking questions here is really asking *can I wave a whole bunch of mental wands in order to make something mean what I want it to mean*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I upvoted this question because I think it is a great question that deserves better than merely a dismissive "It is ungrammatical". Language is a real, living thing, and so is grammar. They don't exist out of armchair grammarians' flights of fancy. Grammar is a set of rules that DESCRIBE a living, evolving language. What you are saying is essentially everything that is wrong about prescriptivism. No, I didn't "simply point to examples". I first made references to ELU grammar posts. I am going to leave it at that. So much out there online/ELU. I needn't repeat them.

Comment: @EddieKal I also just upvoted it. I don't have a problem with the question; it's interesting. My only problem has been with your comments. If you are accusing me of being prescriptivist (I'm actually not, and go out of my way to be liberal when it comes to alternative uses of grammar), I'd say you've gone *way* too far in the opposite direction, to a point beyond even what a typical descriptivist would allow. ;) I'm saying that this use is asyntactic. But just because *roadside* is not an adverb (or normally used *as* an adverb) doesn't mean its necessarily  *wrong* to use it that way.

Comment: I think it is an adverb here.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "standing roadside' here is simply journalese. It is an elision of "standing at the roadside" or a similar phrase to save space, and then out of habit